# Can I use an MSc lecturer as an academic reference for another MSc degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, recommendation-letter, reference-request

I have a BSc and MSc in Architecture (2011). I am close to completing a second MSc and would like to go for a third MSc in Canada. Can a lecturer from the second MSc be a reference in the 3rd MSc application?

I used a lecturer from my undergraduate studies as an academic reference for the second MSc (the only lecturer I kept in touch with). He has written a lot of references for me and I would love not to bother him this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A lecturer from your most recent academic program would generally be a good choice of referee.